# PHP session variable empty during upload

Tags: php, session, file-upload, upload, progress-bar

PHP [states](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php):

> When the session.upload_progress.enabled INI option is enabled, PHP
>   will be able to track the upload progress of individual files being
>   uploaded.

I check mine beforehand: `echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.enabled");`, returns 1 (true)

> The upload progress will be available in the $_SESSION superglobal
>   when an upload is in progress, and when POSTing a variable of the same
>   name as the session.upload_progress.name INI setting is set to. 
>    When PHP detects such POST requests, it will populate an array in the
>   $_SESSION, where the index is a concatenated value of the
>   session.upload_progress.prefix and session.upload_progress.name INI
>   options.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123" />
 <input type="file" name="file1" />
 <input type="file" name="file2" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
            [PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS] => 123
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [PHPSESSID] => pmbqca8fedqgg3hg6nge41fno2
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
            [file1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => profile.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpPLwrND
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 6946
                )

            [file2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )

    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
    [_SESSION] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

The SESSION variable is completely empty. Why is this?

Comment: *"The SESSION variable is completely empty. Why is this?"* - where are you declaring any session array(s)? All you did was start the session.

Comment: From my understanding PHP does it for you: `When PHP detects such POST requests, it will populate an array in the $_SESSION, where the index is a concatenated value of the session.upload_progress.prefix and session.upload_progress.name INI options`

Comment: See if anything gets thrown with error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: session_start() is there to start a session